# Chicago Biblatex: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: biblatex-chicago

I'm trying to get the Chicago Biblatex package to work, but I haven't found any good example on the web. 
I downloaded the package and put all the relevant files into the working directory. 
But the following tex document gives me an error:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@phdthesis{Doe11,
 title={The Title},
 author={Doe, J.},
 year={2011},
 school={University of Mars}
 },

@article{JohSil05,
 title={EbayesThresh: R programs for Empirical Bayes Thresholding},
 author={Johnstone, I.M. and Silverman, B.W.},
 journal={Journal of Statistical Software},
 volume={12},
 number={8},
 pages={1--38},
 year={2005}
},

@book{Joh11,
title = {Gaussian estimation: Sequence and multiresolution models},
author = {Johnstone, Ian M.},
year = {2011},
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibquote{#1}} % make article titles in     quotes
\DeclareFieldFormat[thesis]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}} % make theses italics
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And here's the error I get

> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
>       restricted \write18 enabled.
>      entering extended mode
>      (./Untitled.tex
>      LaTeX2e <2015/01/01>
>      Babel <3.9l> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
>      Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
>
> LaTeX Warning: File `Untitled.bib' already exists on the system.
>                     Not generating it from this source.
>
> (./biblatex-chicago.sty
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
>
> Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend.
>      (biblatex)                To use BibTeX, load biblatex with 
>      (biblatex)                the "backend=bibtex" option.
>
> (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex2.sty
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty))))
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
>      (/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
>      (./chicago-authordate.bbx) (./chicago-authordate.cbx
>      (./chicago-dates-common.cbx
>
> ./chicago-dates-common.cbx:156: LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.
>
> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
>      Type  H   for immediate help.
>       ...
>
> l.156 \DeclareBibliographyOption[bo
>                                         olean]{genallnames}[true]{%
>      ?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you notice the warning message "LaTeX Warning: File 'Untitled.bib' already exists on the system. Not generating it from this source." What happens if you load the `filecontents` package explicitly (before `\begin{filecontents}`, obviously) and rerun latex, biber, and latex?

Comment: A separate query: Which version of the `biblatex-chicago` package is loaded by your system? Is it version 3.4, dated 2016/06/01?

Comment: Did you notice that the typesetting stopped at line 156 and the declared variable type was 'bo olean' instead of 'boolean'? Do you have an old copy of the biblatex-chicago package? I have no problem typesetting with a fully updated TL-2016.

Comment: I just downloaded the biblatex-chicago package this morning from CTAN, version 1.0rc2 2017-03-26. I also downloaded biber this morning, so it should also be up to date. I'm not 100% sure whether biber is correctly installed. I'm using texstudio and changed in the setting the default bibliography to biber, and everything compiles correctly and displays the bibliography unless I try to use this biblatex-chicago package.

Answer (score 1):

The recent version of `biblatex-chicago` (2016/06/07) complies with recent changes in the `biber` command and the `biblatex` package.

If you downloaded a recent copy of the package, then used it with TL 2015, you may have a mismatch among executable programs and package dependencies. The `biber` program, `biblatex` package, and `biblatex-Chicago` dependent package all track together. Thus, in March 2016 updates to `biblatex-Chicago` allowed working with `biblatex` 3.3. The May and June releases segued into `biblatex` 3.4. Currently, `biblatex-chicago` has needed no updates for `biblatex` 3.5 through 3.7. Considerable updates have occurred with `biber`, as we see [here](http://ftp.math.purdue.edu/mirrors/ctan.org/biblio/biber/Changes). Thus, your issue is likely the result of changes and bug fixes in recent versions not working with your older distribution.

I would recommend updating to TL 2016 (or the latest TL as one reads this) and ensure that you expunge all the temporary files created by `biber` and `biblatex` so that you have no remaining cruft. Same for `aux` files. Then recompile. Your example file TeXes nicely on TL 2016.